# How to do a project-wide find and replace in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I'm trying to do a project-wide find/replace in Spacemacs.  I tried this:

1. `SPC s a p`
2. Type the text I want to replace.
3. `C-c C-e`

At this point Spacemacs tells me `text is read-only`.  What am I missing to be able to preform the edit operation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `SPC p R` to use `projectile-replace` which *runs interactive query-replace on all files in the project*.

Comment: Thanks for this. It might be worth noting, that the interactive find/replace wont save the buffers.  It looks like we can use `SPC f S` to use `evil-write-all` for saving all unsaved buffers.

Comment: This really helped me :D `sed` wasn't enough. Thanks!

Comment: This was a life saver as I went to fix several imports across 70+ files lol. Thanks!

Comment: `SPC p %` does the same thing but has regex functionality included